# Fade transition in JavaScript slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, graphics

I want to have a slide show in my web page with fading transition between the images but it's not working.

```
<body>
 <!-- Css Work -->
<style>
    img#ssio{
        position:absolute;
        opacity:1;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    img#ssie{
        opacity:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<!-- JS Work -->

<script>
    var ssion = 1;
    var ssien = 2;
    function slide() {
        document.getElementById("ssio").src = "../images/slideshow/" + ssion + ".jpg";
        document.getElementById("ssie").src = "../images/slideshow/" + ssien + ".jpg";
        ssion += 2;
        ssien += 2;
        if (ssien == 6) {
            ssion = 1;
            ssien = 2;
        }
        setTimeout(slide, 5000);
    }
    function fader() {
        document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity = 1 - document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity;
        document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity = 1 - document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity;
        console.log(document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity, document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity)
        setTimeout(fader, 5000);
    }
</script>


<img id="ssio" src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="slideshow" style="width:100%;height:80%;" />
<img id="ssie" src="../images/slideshow/2.jpg" alt="slideshow" style="width:100%;height:80%;" />
<button onclick="slide(),fader()">start</button>
```

When I see the log, it seems that JavaScript doesn't respect the opacity values which are already defined in the style tag. The console says the opacity of the images is always the same.

By the way, if anyone can come up with a better way to write this code or make it simpler, please tell.

Comment: Why don't you use Jquery ?

Comment: i'm so much for pure html-javascript-css i dont want anything in between.

Comment: Is there any real argument not to use jQuery? It is basically made for this kind of thing. And it's just as javascript as javascript itself.

Comment: dude!i know i can do this with jquery.thank you for your recommendation.but, here and now, i'm asking how can i do it with javascript, using no library or anything.if it really bothers you, you can see it like i want to practice my javascript!or like! i want to make a new library to compete jquery!:D.see it as a challenge!

Comment: Practice capitalizing your sentences, dude. Shift+(letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is another way to implement a slideshow. I wrote it just now because I found your code to be pretty confusing, not to mention difficult to extend to further images.

To use my slideshow implementation, put your images inside the `div` with the ID `slides`. Once the images load, `Slideshow.load` runs. It wraps each image inside a `div` of class `slide`. It also enables the `start` button so that you can click on it to start the slideshow.

Another important thing that happens in `Slideshow.load` is the sizing of the picture frames. All of the frames are sized to the maximum width and height over all images. This allows each frame to fully hide the image behind it.

The fading transition is accomplished by setting the `zIndex` style attribute of the next image to 1000, which effectively brings it into the foreground. The current image has an opacity of 1 and the next image has 0. As we increase the opacity of the next image, it obscures the current image. When the next image reaches full opacity, its `zIndex` is reset to 0. After a pause, `Slideshow.slideIndex` is incremented modulo the number of images, and the fading process starts over.

When you run the following snippet, I recommend that you go to full-page mode so that you can appreciate the image sizes.

```js
var Slideshow = {
  pictureFadeSeconds: 1,
  pictureHoldSeconds: 1,
  updatesPerSecond: 30
};

Slideshow.fade = function () {
  var slides = Slideshow.slides,
      index = Slideshow.slideIndex,
      slide = slides[index],
      nextSlide = slides[(index + 1) % slides.length];
  if (nextSlide.style.opacity == 0) {
    nextSlide.style.zIndex = 1000;  // Bring the slide into the foreground.
  }
  Slideshow.opacity +=
      1 / (Slideshow.updatesPerSecond * Slideshow.pictureFadeSeconds);
  nextSlide.style.opacity = Slideshow.opacity;
  if (Slideshow.opacity >= 1) {
    slide.style.opacity = 0;
    nextSlide.style.opacity = 1;
    nextSlide.style.zIndex = 0;   // Put the slide back in the middle ground.
    Slideshow.slideIndex = (index + 1) % slides.length;
    Slideshow.opacity = 0;
    window.setTimeout(Slideshow.fade, 1000 * Slideshow.pictureHoldSeconds);
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(Slideshow.fade, 1000 / Slideshow.updatesPerSecond);
  }
};

Slideshow.load = function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('slides'),
      images = container.getElementsByTagName('img'),
      maxWidth = images[0].offsetWidth,
      maxHeight = images[0].offsetHeight;
  for (var i = 1; i < images.length; ++i) {
    maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, images[i].offsetWidth);
  }
  var slides = Slideshow.slides = new Array(images.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; ++i) {
    var image = images[i],
        slide = slides[i] = document.createElement('div');
    slide.className = 'slide';
    slide.style.width = maxWidth + 'px';
    slide.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(slide, image);
    slide.appendChild(image);
    image.style.left = Math.floor((maxWidth - image.width) / 2) + 'px';
    image.style.top = Math.floor((maxHeight - image.height) / 2) + 'px';
  }
  var index = Slideshow.slideIndex = 0,
      slide = slides[index],
      nextSlide = slides[(index + 1) % slides.length];
  slide.style.opacity = 1;
  Slideshow.opacity = 0;
  var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
  startButton.onclick = function () {
    startButton.parentNode.removeChild(startButton);
    Slideshow.fade();
  };
  startButton.disabled = false;
};

window.onload = Slideshow.load;
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #000;
}
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
}
#startButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <img src="http://michaellaszlo.com/so/slideshow/assets/apple.jpg" alt="apple" />
  <img src="http://michaellaszlo.com/so/slideshow/assets/pear.jpg" alt="pear" />
  <img src="http://michaellaszlo.com/so/slideshow/assets/orange.jpg" alt="orange" />
  <img src="http://michaellaszlo.com/so/slideshow/assets/banana.jpg" alt="banana" />
  <img src="http://michaellaszlo.com/so/slideshow/assets/pineapple.jpg" alt="pineapple" />
  <img src="http://michaellaszlo.com/so/slideshow/assets/kiwi.jpg" alt="kiwi" />
</div>

<button id="startButton" disabled>start</button>
```

Comment: I dont know what made my code so confusing bc at least, its length is half of yours!and about extending!actually my code is way easier to extend as you only need to add the pictures in the folder and then change the 5 in the if to 5000 and you are done!but in your code you should write 4993 more image tags and edit their src!after adding the images!if you want you can read my posted answer to see how it gets fixed!btw, my question was, why doesn't my code work, and how to simplify it!not how to make a slideshow.thank you for your answer anyways!:)best wishes.

Comment: You have to rename your image files to sequential numbers, don't you? My code doesn't require that. Also, how do you make images of different sizes fade in on top of each other? Half of my code is devoted to handling image dimensions properly.

Comment: yeah i have to do that, but you, you have to copy their names in your src which is sure harder!well, in my case images are the same size and, i think you could easily fix that dimension thing by adding vertical-align:middle and text-align:center to your div!

Comment: I can make images dynamically either by adding a couple of lines in the front end or by generating the tags at the back end. To determine the size of the picture frame, it's necessary to examine the image sizes.

Comment: Well:)ok!I still think you can make it simpler, but i think its not nice to continue this conversation!we are programers, and we work together!and we should enjoy each other's ideas and learn from it:)i'm sure you are much more experienced and a better programer than me, and i respect you:)and really, i'm so thankful that you took the time and wrote this whole snippet for me:)and now i will try to read it carefully, and learn from it:)best wishes for you, buddy;)

Comment: I like your idea of using a CSS transition property. Best wishes to you, too.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fixed it:

```
<body>

<!-- Css Work -->

<style>
    img#ssio{
        transition:opacity 1s;
        position:absolute;
        opacity:1;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    img#ssie{
        transition:opacity 1s;
        opacity:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<!-- JS Work -->

<script>
    var ssion = 1;
    var ssien = 2;
    function slide() {
        document.getElementById("ssie").src = "../images/slideshow/" + ssien + ".jpg";
        ssion += 2;
        ssien += 2;
        if (ssien == 13) {
            ssion = 1;
            ssien = 2;
        }
        setTimeout(slide, 8000);
        setTimeout(slidesupport, 4000)
    }
    function slidesupport() {
        document.getElementById("ssio").src = "../images/slideshow/" + ssion + ".jpg";
    }
    function fader() {
        document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity = document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity;
        document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity = 1 - document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity;
        setTimeout(fader, 4000);
    }
</script>


<img id="ssio" src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="slideshow" style="width:100%;height:80%;" />
<img id="ssie" src="../images/slideshow/2.jpg" alt="slideshow" style="width:100%;height:80%;" />
<button onclick="slide(),fader()">start</button>
```